# How do I get the absolute value of an integer without using Math.abs?

Tags: javascript, function, integer, absolute-value

How do I get the absolute value of a number *without* using math.abs?

This is what I have so far:

```js
function absVal(integer) {
    var abs = integer * integer;
    return abs^2;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with `abs^2`? I think you meant to divide, right? (`return abs/2`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and the [unary negation operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_negation_%28-%29):

```
function absVal(integer) {
  return integer < 0 ? -integer : integer;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also use [`>> (Sign-propagating right shift)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Right_shift)

```
function absVal(integer) {
    return (integer ^ (integer >> 31)) - (integer >> 31);;
}
```

Note: this will work only with integer

Answer (score 3):

Since the absolute value of a number is "how far the number is from zero", a negative number can just be "flipped" positive (if you excuse my lack of mathematical terminology =P):

```
var abs = (integer < 0) ? (integer * -1) : integer;
```

Alternatively, though I haven't benchmarked it, it may be faster to subtract-from-zero instead of multiplying (i.e. `0 - integer`).

Comment: I'd be shocked if subtracting from 0 is slower than an if statement

Comment: @taylorc93 No, no - not in place of the entire ternary statement, in place of the `(integer * -1)` portion... I probably should've written that one all the way out =P

Comment: Ahhhh, that makes more sense now.  Yeah, that would be worth benchmarking but unless this code is being run millions of times in the program, I don't think it would make too much of a difference

Answer (score 3):

Late response, but I think this is what you were trying to accomplish:

```
function absVal(integer) {
   return (integer**2)**.5;
}
```

It squares the integer then takes the square root.  It will eliminate the negative.

Comment: Interesting solution. Although I would go for @Guffa's answer

Answer (score 0):

Check if the number is less than zero! If it is then mulitply it with -1;

Answer (score -1):

There's no reason why we can't borrow [Java's implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Math.java#Math.abs%28float%29).

```js
    function myabs(a) {
      return (a <= 0.0) ? 0.0 - a : a;
    }

    console.log(myabs(-9));
```

How this works:

- if the given number is less than or zero

  - subtract the number from 0, which the result will always be `> 0`
- else return the number (because it's `> 0`)

Comment: This is not a good solution: this function performs a substraction if a equals zero, but 0.0-0.0 is already 0.0 so `(a <0.0)` is better. Secondly, there is no substraction needed because there is the unary negate operator.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. My overarching point was addressing that if you have a well-solved problem you need to implement, look at other known working solutions and use that.

Comment: That's a good point, but Java's way seems not to be the best :)