# Is there a better way to convert negative numbers to positive in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

**Problem:** some numbers are positive some are not. Here is my function to convert negative numbers to positive ones and leave positive numbers untouched. Is there a better way of doing it in JavaScript?

```js
function intAbs(integer) {

    if(isNaN(integer)) {
        throw 'NaN';
    }

    if(parseInt(integer, 10) !== integer) {
        throw 'Not an integer';
    }

    n = integer * integer;

    var x = 1;
    var e = 1;

    while(!(e < 0.1 && e > -0.1)) {
        x = (n / x + x) / 2;
        e = n - x * x;
    }

    return parseInt(x);

}
```

**Update:** I don't think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30268801/how-do-i-get-the-absolute-value-of-an-integer-without-using-math-abs) is a duplicate. I know how to get the absolute value of an integer without `Math.abs()`. You can see in this question. I have already accepted the answer which states **"Yes, there is a better way"** and it's not ambiguous.

**Update #2:** This question is marked as a duplicate of [Get the absolute value of a number in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9353929/get-the-absolute-value-of-a-number-in-javascript), but this does not address problem `if(is there a better way of calculating abs than exactly this algorithm)`. I give up.

Comment: What's wrong with `Math.abs(whatever)`?

Comment: I will not accept it If it will be closed.

Comment: The poster wants to require integer arguments only, apparently.

Comment: I feel a huge peer presure now.

Comment: And are you trying to square the number, then take the square root with the Babylonian method? That's an amazingly roundabout way to do it.

Comment: Instead of ranting on about other users, why don't you improve your post so people can understand what you're asking? See [ask] for more information.

Comment: It is far from roundaboutest you could do. @Qantas, thanks for advice. I will try to improve it.

Comment: Similar SO question: [How do I get the absolute value of an integer without using Math.abs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30268801/how-do-i-get-the-absolute-value-of-an-integer-without-using-math-abs). There are a couple of interesting answers.

Comment: Now that you changed your question, there is an even better way: `-number`. Could you please make up your mind what this question is about? *edit*: ah.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for your remark. I've updated problem definition.

Comment: *"but this does not address problem if(is there a better way of calculating abs than exactly this algorithm)."* I see you unaccepted the answer here, so I assume you are not satisfied with the answer that `Math.abs` is the better way? Is this actually an algorithm question, not JS specific? In this case, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30268801/how-do-i-get-the-absolute-value-of-an-integer-without-using-math-abs seems to be the better duplicate. Or are you just changing your question for the sake of it, hoping at some point it won't be a duplicate anymore?

Comment: And now you accepted the answer again (or I was just blind). Your behavior is really confusing and the intend of the question not clear at all. If you accept `Math.abs` as answer, then it is a duplicate of the currently linked question.

Comment: @FelixKling I was just exploring possibilities to delete this question. This answer is acceptable. Everything is ok. No jokes here. Lesson learned. Points transferred. Nobody harmed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way: Math.abs().